# 80-90s TV (?) movie with symbiotic, liquid-looking alien that shocks people touching it

Tags: story-identification, movie

I vaguely recall the plot being a symbiotic alien transfers to humans from a black rock and controls them. One scene even showed them having the rock in a glass container with rubber gloves so they can handle it later on and as they put their hand close to it they could even see the alien reach out to the hand.

The alien looked like a liquid and shocked anyone when they touched it. Kind of like:

[image: a small smooth black rock]

Have a feeling I saw it on the Sci Fi channel well before it was Syfy.

Comment: Also, is it The Invasion? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0427392/

Answer (score 5):

I think it's the TV movie [*Invasion*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118452/), (1997), with Luke Perry.  (Different from the one suggested by Mooz.)

> Small rocks fall from the sky which, when touched, trigger a latent
>   virus that has always existed in humans and begins mutating them into
>   an alien species.

Comment: I don't think it's what you're looking for, but just in case: It is not a movie but the original Outer Limits had a black and white episode titled "Corpus Earthling" with black rocks which were aliens that could control people.